# How to submit local jobs with dsl.pipeline

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

Trying to run and debug a pipeline locally. Pipeline is imeplemented with `azure.ml.component.dsl.pipeline`. When I try to set `default_compute_target='local'`, the compute target cannot be found:

```
local not found in workspace, assume this is an AmlCompute
...
File "/home/amirabdi/miniconda3/envs/stm/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ml/component/run_settings.py", line 596, in _get_compute_type
    raise InvalidTargetSpecifiedError(message="Cannot find compute '{}' in workspace.".format(compute_name))
azure.ml.component._util._exceptions.InvalidTargetSpecifiedError: InvalidTargetSpecifiedError:
        Message: Cannot find compute 'local' in workspace.
        InnerException None
        ErrorResponse
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Cannot find compute 'local' in workspace."
    }
}
```

The local run, for example, can be achieved with `azureml.core.ScriptRunConfig`.

```py
src = ScriptRunConfig(script="train.py", compute_target="local", environment=myenv)
run = exp.submit(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have different types of [compute targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-compute-target#train) and one of those is local computer.

1. Create an experiment

   `from azureml.core import Experiment`

   `experiment_name = 'my_experiment'`

   `experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name=experiment_name)`
2. Select the compute target where we need to run

   `compute_target='local'`
3. If the compute_target is not mentioned or ScriptRunConfig is not mentioned, then AzureML will run the script locally

   `from azureml.core import Environment`

   `myenv = Environment("user-managed-env")`

   `myenv.python.user_managed_dependencies = True`
4. Create the script job, based on the procedure mentioned in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-set-up-training-targets#create-the-script-job-configuration)
5. Submit the experiment

`run = experiment.submit(config=src)`

`run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)`

6. To check for the troubleshooting the procedure, check with [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-set-up-training-targets#troubleshooting)

Comment: I'm particularly asking about `dsl.pipeline`. I can run jobs locally with `experiment.submit()` as shown in the question. But, can't do the same with `dsl.pipelines`.

Comment: you are using an internal preview version of SDK. pipeline local run is not a public preview feature yet. please raise a support ticket to discuss internally.